# CW construction of Lens spaces Hatcher

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I am working through [Hatcher's book](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) and I am having trouble while understanding the CW-complex structure of Lens spaces. It is on page 145. He proves it constructing it in an inductive process. I upload two pictures:

[image: hat1]

[image: hat2]

I think I understand all the previous ideas but I struggle with the text in yellow. I just don't see that. Why we have that? Are the $B_j^{2n-1}$ with $j \in \{1, \cdots ,m\}$ a cover of $S^{2n-3}$? I think there is something I have missed somewhere. Maybe I am not thinking about it adequately?

Some of my pictures so far are these (for the case $n=2$):

[image]

Maybe just explaining it with different words could help me to understand it. I am afraid I can not explain better.

Thanks in advance and any help would be appreciated. Also note there are two related questions:
[CW structure of lens space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580627/cw-structure-of-lens-space?rq=1)
[CW construction of a generalized lens space from Hatcher](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772136/cw-construction-of-a-generalized-lens-space-from-hatcher?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I got an answer to my own question. the $B_j^{2n-1}$ with $j \in \{1, \cdots ,m\}$  cover  $S^{2n-3}$. That's easy to see when one write down the analytical formulas which are suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772136/cw-construction-of-a-generalized-lens-space-from-hatcher?lq=1) as a comment.